# regex pattern including underscore "&#95" fails validation

Tags: regex, xsd

Newb alert!

I have a Schema Regex pattern defined as

```
    <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]([A-Z0-9;&#32;&#45;&#95;]){5,7}"/>
```

My intent is to allow spaces, hyphens, and underscores in the grouping. Unfortunately, the addition of the underscore `&#95;` to the pattern also allows other special characters to be valid when they should not be. The below sample element texts that include the `=` sign fail when the underscore is removed from the pattern.

I'm developing in XMLSpy for Excel 2013. As far as I can tell the underscore character, despite being escaped, appears to be acting as some form of wildcard. Curiously, testing on the Regex101 site catches the validation errors.

Sample element text:

- GEN -1    validates
- GEN =-1   validates but should not
- GEN =1    validates but should not

Comment: Try to do it this way `[A-Z][A-Z\s-\d]{5,7}` or even better this way: `[A-Z]+\s-\d+`

Comment: **/s** is "any whitespace character" which is contrary to limiting allowable characters to only space, hyphen and underscore. This does not represent a viable solution.